# Not occupying full screen in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi in the below layout am getting bottom some space .Not taking fill parent to my layout.want to occupy the layout fully.

i have designed screen but i have at the end of the layout am getting white color border . want to occupy the layout full screen .but at the end of the layout it was showing white border.

can any one please help me .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1c1c1c"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".DeviceControlActivity">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_centerparent="true">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/litm_havells" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_lit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="@drawable/litm" />


                <com.github.angads25.toggle.LabeledSwitch
                    android:id="@+id/ligt_switch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:colorBorder="#2a9ed1"
                    app:colorOn="#2a9ed1"
                    app:on="true" />


                <com.github.angads25.toggle.LabeledSwitch
                    android:id="@+id/lable_auto"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_lit"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:colorBorder="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:on="true"
                    app:textOff="Manual"
                    app:textOn="Auto" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="#1c1c1c"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#212121"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="7dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#a1979e" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_tick1"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/classic"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_classic"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Classic"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorClassic"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="#212121"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="7dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#efb614" />

                    <ImageView

                        android:id="@+id/img_tick2"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/casual1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_casual"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Casual"
                        android:textColor="#efb614"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="#212121"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="7dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#32cc5d" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_tick3"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/natural"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_natural"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Natural"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorNatural"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="#212121"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="7dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#ede925" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_tick4"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/smart"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_smart"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Smart"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorSmart"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="#212121"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="7dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#28dce5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_tick5"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/meeting"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_meeting"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Meeting"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorMeeting"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />


                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="#212121"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="7dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#2a9ed1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_tick6"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cool"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_cool"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Cool"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorCool"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="#1c1c1c"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_intenisty_titiel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Intensity"
                        android:textColor="#2a9ed1"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/intensity"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="@id/txt_intenisty_titiel"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="134dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_style"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_color_titiel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Temperature"
                        android:textColor="#2a9ed1"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/intensity1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="134dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_style"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="#1c1c1c"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <Button
                    android:id="@id/txt_reset1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
                    android:text="RESET"
                    android:textColor="#2a9ed1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/txt_save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SAVE"
                    android:textColor="#2a9ed1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_scheduler"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/image1"
                    android:text="SCHEDULER"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `android:fillViewport="true"` in your scrollview

Answer (score 3):

You should use match_parent for scroll view height...

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: using Large screen still am getting white color border